# Find values from pandas series in a list and return the index of the match

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to do this without a loop?

I am thinking about something like this:

```
pd_series = pd.Series(["c", "d", "a", "b"])
list_map  = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
In [1]: pd_series.find_in(list_map)
Out [1]: 
0    2
1    3
2    0
3    1
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an *actual map* instead of a list, assuming the elements are unique:

```
>>> actual_map = dict(zip(list_map, range(len(list_map))))
>>> actual_map
{'d': 3, 'b': 1, 'a': 0, 'c': 2}
>>> pd_series.map(actual_map)
0    2
1    3
2    0
3    1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

You can using `np.vectorize`+`get_loc`

```
np.vectorize(pd.Index(pd_series).get_loc)(list_map)
Out[499]: array([2, 3, 0, 1])
```

Comment: Did you mean `np.vectorize(pd.Index(list_map).get_loc)(pd_series)`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yep : -)